# Don't know how to redirect to url from mail after login in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

so I have this application. It has newly got sso via kerberos but is also running ldap as a fallback option. There is a routingpage that directs people to the homepage if authenticated by kerberos or leads them to the loginpage if not. Now I was made aware of the fact, that a lot of people actually go first to the application via a link they receive via mail where they need to approve something and they are annoyed that they get directed to the homepage after clicking the link because that is how it's implemented that after authentification they will go to the homepage.

So now I found a way to get redirect them straight to the approvalpage from the e-mail via kerberos but I can't seem to make it work via kerberos. I keep getting directed to the homepage.
So this is my attempt:

RoutingPage:

```
public class RouterPage extends BasePage {
  public SSORouterPage () {
    super();
    AppSession session = (AppSession) SecureWebSession.get();
    String approvalLink = getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("approval_link").toString();
    if (approvalLink != null) {
      session.setApprovalLink(approvalLink);
    }
    if (!session.singleSignOn()) {
      log.warn("User not logged in, redirecting to login page");
      if (session.hasApprovalLink()) {
        approvalLink = session.getApprovalLink();
        session.setApprovalLink(null);
        setResponsePage(LoginPage.class, getApprovalPageParameters(approvalLink));
      } else {
        setResponsePage(LoginPage.class);
      }
    } else {
      String name = Optional
          .ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication).map(
              Authentication::getName).orElse("undefined");
      log.info("Sucessfull sign in for {}", name);
      if (session.hasApprovalLink()) {
        approvalLink = session.getApprovalLink();
        session.setApprovalLink(null);

        setResponsePage(new ApprovalPage(getApprovalPageParameters(approvalLink)));
      } else {
        setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
      }
    }

  }
```

LoginPage

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4297836260248255954L;

    public static final String LOGIN_PANEL_ID = "panel";


    public LoginPage() {
        super();

        if (AuthenticatedWebSession.class.isAssignableFrom(getSession().getClass()) && ((AuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).isSignedIn()) {
                continueToOriginalDestination();

        }
    }

    public LoginPage(final PageParameters pageParameters){
        super(pageParameters);
        if (AuthenticatedWebSession.class.isAssignableFrom(getSession().getClass()) && ((AuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).isSignedIn()) {
            setResponsePage(new ApprovalPage(pageParameters));

        }
    }
```

The constructor with the PageParameters is clearly called because I can see them in the url, why do I get directed to the homepage? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `Component#continueToOriginalDestination()`. See its [javadoc](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/4affb7b18424e40663239ac9c93d9ec33a432541/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/Component.java#L1061). Its purpose is to continue to the originally requested page after an interception like "you need to login first". You need to use `#redirectToInterceptPage(LoginPage.class)` with it.